# cannot open destfile...reason 'Invalid argument' in Rstudio1.1.447

Tags: r, download

I am a beginner in R.
My script is:

```
output_folder <-"X:\\My_R_result\\"

url<-paste("https://climexp.knmi.nl/data/icmip5_pr_Amon_ens_rcp45_79-91E_26-31N_n_su_001.dat",sep="")

destfile<-paste(output_folder,"001.dat",sep="")

download.file(url,destfile,method="auto",quiet = FALSE, mode="W",cacheOK=TRUE)

print(download.file)
print("finished")
```

It pop ups with

> Error in download.file(url, destfile, method = "auto", quiet = FALSE, 
>   : cannot open destfile 'X:\My_R_result\001.dat', reason 'Invalid
>   argument'.

Could you please tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: `mode="W"` should be `mode="w"`. Tip: you can use `paste0` to replace `paste(   , sep = "")`

Comment: Thank you, Tung. It works with "w"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
I changed your paste() to paste0() commands. The mode="W" should be a lower case "w".

```
output_folder <-"X:\\My_R_result\\"
url<-paste0("https://climexp.knmi.nl/data/icmip5_pr_Amon_ens_rcp45_79-91E_26-31N_n_su_001.dat")
destfile<-paste0(output_folder,"001.dat")
download.file(url,destfile,method="auto",quiet = FALSE, mode="w",cacheOK=TRUE)
print("finished")
```

And you cannot print(download.file), as you would only print the function itself, not the downloaded text. To print the text inside the downloaded data, you have to load it in R.

```
data <- read.table(file = destfile)
print(data)
```